# ghost docker container mysql self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: azure, docker, ssl, ghost-blog, azure-mysql-database

I am trying to get my Ghost Blog (https://ghost.org/) running in a Azure Docker Container.
In the Ghost documentation they describe how to configure the SSL connection for a MySQL database. In Azure I have a flexible MySQL server and I have downloaded the PEM certificate file. I have exported it to a text file, according to the Ghost Container (documentation)
https://ghost.org/docs/config/#configuration-options

In the documentation they tell me to use this command for the export to text:

(you can get the single line string with awk '{printf "%s\n", $0}' DigiCertGlobalRootCA.pem)

My Ghost Docker configuration looks like this now:

```
  database__connection__ssl__ca: -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDrzCCApegAwI ... etc ... d4=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n
```

But every time when I try to start the container now I get the following error

```
m Ghost server started in 3.906s
2023-02-19T11:09:07.296559486Z [2023-02-19 11:09:07] [31mERROR[39m self signed certificate in certificate chain
2023-02-19T11:09:07.296630486Z [31m
2023-02-19T11:09:07.296638786Z [31mself signed certificate in certificate chain[39m
2023-02-19T11:09:07.296645186Z
2023-02-19T11:09:07.296650786Z [33m"Unknown database error"[39m
```

Is there anyone else how has this problem?

Comment: There's no service called Azure Docker Container

Comment: It's an Azure Container App, but that's not relevant. My problem is with the container itself.

Comment: Did you find the issue? I have the same Problem using Azure App Service with Azure Database for MySQL flexible server